# Clickable ImageView during TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, translation

I have an ImageView and I want to translate it to a random spot on the screen:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,100);
anim.setDuration(2000);
img.startAnimation(anim);
```

This works fine. But I want to have a clickable ImageView during the whole animation. 
At this moment it only works at the beginning and at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use Animator class and not Animation class because when using TranslateAnimation, you are animating a image of a view and not a View it self.

I think this is explained somewhere there
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

And on the next page